# How to make script run when key pressed?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to create a small bit of code that will print the integer stored in the variable 'money' when the m key is pressed. To show what I mean, here is a bit of the code. I know this is nowhere near the right way to write the script but I wanted to write it in a way that would show any reader what the goal was, since I don't have any idea how to get to that goal.

```
#view money
while True:
    pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()
    if pressedKey == 'm':
        print money
```

Comment: I added the Python 2 tag since your code is not valid Python 3. If you're looking for non-version specific answers, you can update your question with an [edit]. Do note that all versions of Python 2 have [reached their end of life](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), and will no longer receive updates or security fixes. If at all possible, you should transition to Python 3.

Comment: Every time Python 2 is used, a kitten dies.

Answer (score 0):

this code checks if you press the key "m" and will print the variable

```
import keyboard
money = 0
while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "m":
        print(money)
        break
```

Comment: this is on python3, not python2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyboard` module

## install keyboard

```py
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'keyboard'])
```

## Use keyboard

```py
import keyboard
import time

money = '100$'
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('m'):
        print(f'Your Have: {money}')
        break
    #time.sleep(1)
```